# Changing my eBook reader. Any way to take my kindle books with me?

Tags: kindle, epub, kindle-paperwhite

I am changing from Kindle for reading eBooks onto a different eReader platform. I've purchased a couple of eBooks for Kindle on the Amazon platform but those books I didn't start reading yet. Additionally there are some Amazon/Kindle books I've purchased that I would like to read again and therefor be on my new eReader as well.

I had a hard time finding relevant information, I guess because it's not possible or damn hard (for obvious reasons I understand why Amazon doesn't want that to be easy).

So is this a hopeless endeavour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if the books have DRM (Digital Rights Management) or not.

If they do then you can only read them on Amazon devices or with a Kindle app on PCs Macs Android or ios.

If not DRM then download them to a computer using the transfer by USB option on the "manage your contents and devices" page on Amazon on the Web.

Then you need to convert your books to a different format usually. .epub  The usual way is to use the program calibre. https://calibre-ebook.com. Some calibre plugins might be able to import the books from where the kindle app stores the books on a computer, look at kfx importer

Comment: That has worked very well. Thank you!

Comment: @LarsBlumberg you can't have done all that so soon.

Comment: I actually found it out myself shortly ago, exactly the way you described.

Comment: @LarsBlumberg on stackexchange you are allowed to answer your own questions

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to write down your answer. You have just been faster than me!